# Macro calling issues after converting a function to a Macro

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, macros

I had this function:

```
void hex_display(void const *v_ptr, int num)
{
    uchar const *ptr = v_ptr;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
        if(i != 0)
        {
            if(((i%4) == 0) && ((i%16) != 0))
            {
                fprintf(fp, "\t");
            }
            if((i%16) == 0)
                fprintf(fp, "\n");
            fprintf(fp, "%02x", ptr[i]);
        }
        else
            fprintf(fp, "%02x", ptr[i]);
    }
    fprintf(fp, "\n");
}
```

which I converted into a macro as below:

```
#define hex_display(v_ptr, num)\
{\
    uchar const *ptr = v_ptr;\
    int i;\
    for (i=0; i<num; i++)\
    {\
        if(i != 0)\
        {\
            if(((i%4) == 0) && ((i%16) != 0))\
            {\
                fprintf(fp, "\t");\
            }\
            if((i%16) == 0)\
                fprintf(fp, "\n");\
            fprintf(fp, "%02x", ptr[i]);\
        }\
        else\
            fprintf(fp, "%02x", ptr[i]);\
    }\
    fprintf(fp, "\n");\
}
```

I have another Macro print_struct:

```
#define print_struct(str)  hex_display((str), sizeof(*(str)))
```

ie, whenever I call print_struct, it internally calls hex_display. And each time, it gives me this warning:

> warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by
>   default]

What am I doing wrong? How do I remove this warning?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Is the macro form of the function actually named `print_mem()` but you mis-typed?

Comment: The answers explain where you went wrong in defining the macro, but IMHO your chief mistake was making it a macro to begin with :-) Why do you want it to be a macro?

Comment: Still from your last question (number 21326738) transforming your function into a macro doesn't make any sense to me. Just don't do it. It brings you nothing, no performance gain whatever, only obfuscates your code. Really, don't.

Comment: uchar const *ptr = (void *)v_ptr;\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line in the (rather horrible, imo) macro:

```
uchar const *ptr = v_ptr;
```

This treats `v_ptr` as a pointer to `uchar`, but if it isn't, then there's a conversion occuring which the compiler is warning about.

Add a cast:

```
uchar const *ptr = (uchar *) v_ptr;\
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function had void* argument, so types checking was not working in it. In the macro there is no void* anymore, and when you use macro with char* argument, its first line assigns char* to uchar*, which causes the warning. Change uchar* to char* or add a cast.